# Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

My MySQL query is coming up with this error message when I try to pass information from a form on my web application:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'db'.'frs_Payment'('payid', 'amount', 'paydatetime', 'empnin', 'custid', 'pstatusid', 'ptid')
         VALUES('','".$amount"','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','".$empnin."','".$custid"','"2"','".$ptid."');");
```

It is the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP feature which is causing the error. I am aware this may be because of the speech marks. But I've added and removed them from the timestamp and the query still won't run.

Do I need to add speech marks elsewhere?

Comment: What's the value of $amount? I see no escaping here, so if you were to have a rogue single quote in that variable it would screw up no matter what. Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated. look into mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements

Comment: This has nothing to do with mysql, this is a php syntax error

Comment: `'current_timestamp' ` means you try to insert the text current_timestamp into the field. If you want to insert the current time, use `current_timestamp()` form. But this is independent from the error message in the question.

Comment: A missing [string concatenation operator (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) is missing between `$amount` and `"','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','"`. Another one is missing after `$custid`. Your MySQL query doesn't have a chance to run because the PHP code never ran because it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a typo in your PHP syntax. Change:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'db'.'frs_Payment'('payid', 'amount', 'paydatetime', 'empnin', 'custid', 'pstatusid', 'ptid')
         VALUES('','".$amount"','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','".$empnin."','".$custid"','"2"','".$ptid."');");
```

to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'db'.'frs_Payment'('payid', 'amount', 'paydatetime', 'empnin', 'custid', 'pstatusid', 'ptid')
         VALUES('','".$amount."','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP','".$empnin."','".$custid."','2','".$ptid."');");
```

Typos are self–explaining.

Also note, that [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'db'.'frs_Payment'('payid', 'amount', 'paydatetime', 'empnin', 'custid', 'pstatusid', 'ptid')
     VALUES('','$amount',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'$empnin','$custid','2','$ptid');");
```

No need to break up a double-quoted string and you had way too many quotes everywhere. Also, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a sql function, not a string literal.